# Video streaming with NodeJS and HapiJS

Tags: node.js, express, hapi.js

I'd like to stream video files using NodeJS but with HapiJs instead of Express.

Here is what I'd would like to achieve using HapiJS

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

const videoFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'vid.mp4');
const fileSize = fs.statSync(videoFilePath).size;

app.get('/video', (req, res) => {
  const { range } = req.headers;
  const [s, e] = range.replace('bytes=', '').split('-');
  const start = Number(s);
  const end = Number(e) || fileSize - 1;
  res.append('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
  res.append('Content-Range', `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`);
  res.append('Content-Length', end - start + 1);
  res.append('Content-Type', 'video/mp4');
  res.status(206);
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(videoFilePath, { start, end });
  fileStream.pipe(res);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up...');
});
```

How would I do exactly this using HapiJS ( version > 17)?

Answer (score 1):

missing .code(206)

```
return h.response(stream)
        .type("video/mp4")
        .header('Content-type', 'video/mp4')
        .header("Content-Range", `bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`)
        .header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
        .header("Content-Length", contentLength)
        .header("Content-Description", 'File Transfer')
        .code(206)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const Path = require("path");

downloadFile = async (request, h) => {
    try {
        const path = Path.join(__dirname, `../../path`)
        const { size } = fs.statSync(path)
        const { range } = request.headers
        const start = Number((range || '').replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")[0])
        const end = size - 1
        const chunkSize = (end - start) + 1
        const stream = fs.createReadStream(path, { start, end })
        return h.response(stream)
            .header("Content-Range", `bytes ${start}-${end}/${size}`)
            .header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
            .header("Content-Length", chunkSize)
            .type("video/mp4")
            .header('Content-type', 'video/mp4') 
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

module.exports = [

{
        method: "GET",
        path: "/api/url/endpoint/{filename}",
        handler: downloadFile
    }
]
```